# An integral formula involving Bessel functions and an associated Legendre funtion

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions, legendre-functions

Table of Integrals, Series, and Products (8th edition)(I.S.Gradshteyn,I.M.Ryzhik,Daniel Zwillinger, and Victor Moll) contains the following formula.(Page 693)

6.578 $\,$6.11

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\mu+1}K_{\mu}(ax)J_{\nu}(bx)J_{\nu}(cx)dx=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}a^{\mu}b^{-\mu-1}c^{-\mu-1}e^{-(\mu+\frac{1}{2})\pi i}(u^2-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}\mu-\frac{1}{4}} Q_{\nu-\frac{1}{2}}^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}}(u)$$

$$2bcu=a^2+b^2+c^2, \quad \mathrm{Re}\,a > |\mathrm{Im}\, b|+|\mathrm{Im}\,c|, \quad \mathrm{Re}\, \nu > -1, \quad \mathrm{Re}(\mu+\nu) > -1$$

As far as I've checked, this formula is wrong.

Does anyone know the correct formula?

Comment: Please show your work that the equation "is wrong."

Comment: I substituted some numbers and calculated the right and left sides using Mathematica(NIntegrate), but the right and left sides did not match for all the numbers.